# How to check if requested URL is a servlet (in a filter)?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a filter that maps onto all requests:

```
@WebFilter({ "/*" })
```

I use this filter to do url mapping so that i can have vanity urls for my jsps and to handle 404s, however it also means i have to manually add the servlets to process the request chain normally:

```
String requri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI(); //get requested url
String page = "";

if(requri.equals("/contact/") || requri.equals("/contact"))
   page = "contact.jsp";

else if(requri.equals("/about/") || requri.equals("/about"))
   page = "about.jsp";

else if(requri.equals("/SomeServlet"))
   chain.doFilter(request, response); //if requested url is a servlet, then carry on normally

//send requested url to servlet which will then forward user to the appropriate page
request.getRequestDispatcher("/GetPage?page="+page).forward(request, response);
return;
```

It all works great.

But is there a way to get a list of the url mappings for all the servlets? So that i don't have to manually list each url mapping for the servlets.. i.e:

```
else if(requri.equals("/SomeServlet") || requri.equals("/AnotherServlet") || requri.equals("/SomeOtherServlet"))
   chain.doFilter(request, response); //if requested url is a servlet, then carry on normally
```

The ideal:

```
else if(isAServlet(requri))
   chain.doFilter(request, response); //if requested url is a servlet, then carry on normally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in JEE >= JEE 7 there is [`ServletContext.getServletRegistrations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistrations--). It returns a map from servlet names to `ServletRegistration` objects. These have a [`getMappings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#getMappings--) method that gets you the URL mappings for that servlet. You will probably have to process these a bit, e.g. apply the servlet URL mapping rules manually, to see which servlet, if any, would get called.

Comment: That's brilliant, just what was needed. Thanks!